# Proof Expla.: $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A\in M_{n\times n}(F)$ iff $\det(A-\lambda I)=0$?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations, proof-explanation

I don't understand how Theorem 2.5 works in the following proof

[image: theorem5.2]

And my idea of this proof is that: If $\large(A-\lambda I_n)$ is invertible then $v$ has to be $\mathbf0,$ which contradicts the assumption that ["]*there exists a nonzero vector $v$*[..."]. Is this correct?

Here is theorem 2.5

[image: theorem2.5]

Comment: Yes, you are correct.

Comment: @Fimpellizieri: Thank you sir but I also want to know how theorem 2.5 applies here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is:\begin{align}\text{exists }v\neq0\text{ such that }Av=\lambda v&\iff\text{exists }v\neq0\text{ such that }(A-\lambda\operatorname{Id})v=0\\&\iff A-\lambda\operatorname{Id}\text{ is not one-to-one}\\&\iff A-\lambda\operatorname{Id}\text{ is not invertible}\end{align}and it is in this last equivalence that theorem 2.5 is used, since it says that a linear map between vector spaces of the same (finite) dimension is one-to-one if and only if it is onto and that therefore it is one-to-one if and only if it is invertible.

Comment: Oh so it's the existence of $v\not=0$ causes the "not one-to-one" happens?

Comment: Yes, of course, since we always have $(A-\lambda\operatorname{Id})0=0$.